# Cannot re-open from mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, flagging, vote-to-close

Tapping the re-open button when on the mobile site just throws a JS error and jumps you to the top of the page.

Comment: This was already reported on mSO. See [Close and flag links do nothing on mobile site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186622/189912).

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed with the latest push to production